# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: t.resolve is not a function setNativePromise for scratch card functionality at Android app

Tags: angular, ionic4

We want scratch card functionality in our android app developed using ionic 4 with Angular.

We have used this plugins for that:

```
 npm install --save scratchcard-js
```

We take reference from below site

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-ionic-4-adding-scratch-cards-like-google-pay-in-ionic-application-using-javascript-liberary/

Code for that is:

```
createNewScratchCard() {
    const scContainer = document.getElementById('js--sc--container')
    const sc = new ScratchCard('#js--sc--container', {
              scratchType: SCRATCH_TYPE.CIRCLE,
              containerWidth: 300,//scContainer.offsetWidth,
              containerHeight: 300,
              imageForwardSrc: './assets/images/scratchcard.png',
              htmlBackground: '<div class="cardamountcss"><div class="won-amnt">30</div><div class="won-   text">Points<br>Won!</div></div>',
              clearZoneRadius: 40,
              nPoints: 30,
              pointSize: 4,
              callback: () => {
                  console.log('Now the window will reload !')
              }
         })
    // Init
    sc.init();
}
```

but I still get an error.

How can we implement scratch card functionality in our Android app?

Help needed,

Thanks in advance.